# Temporary file not deleted after calling deleteOnExit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, file

This is my current implementation to create a temporary file inside the cache directory on Android. However, this file is supposed to be deleted after I close my app. Yet, this file is still present in my cache directory. My emulator is running Android 12 btw.

```
fun uriToFile(context: Context, uri: Uri): File? {
    val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val fileExtension = getFileExtension(context, uri)
    val fileName = "file_${System.currentTimeMillis()}"
    val directory = context.cacheDir
    val destinationFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".$fileExtension", directory)
    destinationFile.deleteOnExit()

    try {
        val inputStream: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        if (inputStream!=null) {
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(destinationFile)
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var bytesRead: Int
            while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it }!=-1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            }
            outputStream.close()
            inputStream.close()
            return destinationFile
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        //
    }
    return null
}

private fun getFileExtension(context: Context, uri: Uri): String {
    val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri)
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType)
        ?: "unknown"
}
```

I've tried moving around the `destinationFile.deleteOnExit()`, but it didn't work.

Comment: "this file is supposed to be deleted after I close my app" -- what is your definition of "close my app"? `deleteOnExit()` will take effect when your process ends, which is handled by the OS on its own schedule.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/io/File.java#323 "Note that on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination, so calling this method will not ensure that files are deleted"